# 5.6 GB not enough for Cloudera?

Tags: hadoop, out-of-memory, development-environment, cloudera

I am running Cloudera Hadoop on my laptop and Oracle VirtualBox VM.
I have given 5.6 GB out of mine 8 and six from eight cores as well.
And still I am not able to keep it up and running.
Even without load services would not stay up and running and when I try a query at least Hive will be down within 20 minutes. And sometimes they go down like dominoes: one after another.

More memory seemed to help some: with 3GB and all services, Hue was blinking with red colors when the Hue itself managed to get up. And after rebooting it would takes 30 - 60 minutes before I manage to get the system up enough to even try running anything on it.

There has been two sensible notes (that I have managed to find):
- Warning of swapping.
- Crashing note when the system used 26 GB of virtual memory which was not enough.

My dataset is less than one megabyte, so it is hard to understand why the system would go up to dozens of gigabytes, but for whatever was reason for that has passed: now the system is running more steadily around the 5.6 GB that I have given to it after closing down a few services: see my answer to myself.

And still it is just more stable. Right after I got a warning of swapping and the Hive went down again. What could be reason for more-or-less all Hadoop services going down if the VM starts to swap?

I don't have enough reputation to post the picture to here, but when Hive went down again it was swapping 13 pages / second and utilizing 5.9 GB / 5.6 GB. So basically my system starts crashing more-or-less right after it start to swap. "428 pages were swapped to disk in the previous 15 minute(s)"

I have used default installation options as far as hard drive is concerned.
Only addition is a shared folder between Windows and VM. That works somewhat strangely locking files all the time, so I used it just like FTP and only for passing files from one system to another. Thus I can go days without using it, but systems still crash, so that is not the cause either.

Now that the system is mostly up, services crash still about twice a day: Service Monitor and Hive are quite even with their crashing frequency. After those come Activity Monitor and Event Server, which appear to crash always together. I believe Yarn crashes as well, but it gets up on its own. Last time Hive crashed first, and then it got followed by Service Monitor, Hive (second time), Activity Monitor and Event Server all.

---

As swap is disk, perhaps the problem is with disk:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
# swapoff -a
# badblocks -v /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
Checking blocks 0 to 8388607
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found.
# badblocks -vw /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 8388607
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done                                
Reading and comparing: done                                
Testing with pattern 0x55: done                                
Reading and comparing: done                                
Testing with pattern 0xff: done                                
Reading and comparing: done                                
Testing with pattern 0x00: done                                
Reading and comparing: done                                
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found.
```

So nothing wrong with swap disk and I have not noticed any disk error anywhere else either.

Note that you could check file system from Windows side also. But I expect that if you make Windows to fix your Linux file system, you have good chances of destroying your Linux with that, so I did my checks somewhat pessimistically, because AFAIK these commands are safe to execute.

Comment: You haven't stated your problem. "not able to keep it up and running" does not describe a problem.

Comment: You need to specify what size your datasets are? what is your block size?

Answer (score 1):

About half of the services kept going down, so giving more specifics would be a long story.

I succeeded to get the system more stable by closing down flume, hbase, impala, ks_indexer, oozie, spark and sqoop. And by increasing more memory to some remaining services that complained they had not been given enough memory.

Also I fixed couple of thing on the Windows side, I am not sure which one of these helped:
 - MsMpEng.exe kept my hard drive busy. I didn't have permissions to kill it, but I decreased its priority to lowest possible.
 - CcmExec.exe got to loop on my DVD and kept reading it for forever. This I solved by taking the DVD out from the drive. Then later on I killed the process tree to keep it from bothering for a while.
I found these using Windows resource manager.

Answer (score 0):

The VM requires 4GB: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html You should use that.

I am not clear whether you are using the QuickStart VM though. It's set up to run just the essential services and tuned to conserve memory rather than exploit lots of memory.

It sounds like you are running your own installation, on one virtual machine, on your Windows machine. You may be running an entire cluster's worth of services on one desktop machine. Each of these services has master, worker processes, monitoring processes, etc. You don't need most of them.

You also probably have left memory settings at default suitable for a server-class machine of 16+ GB RAM. Remember these services usually run across many machines, not all on one.

Finally, you're clearly swapping, and that makes things incredibly slow. Remember this is all through a VM too!

Bottom line, use the QuickStart VM if you really want a 1-machine cluster tuned correctly. If you want a real cluster or more services, you need more hardware.

Comment: Hi Sean. I used this QuickStart VM stack, yes. If you open the Hardware Requirements, it seems to say that 8 BG is required: http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-1-x.html
Also the file size is 3.7 GB, not 3 GB any more, so the information does not seem to be up to date.

Did I succeed to download "Monday" version, which was not the same as normal? As it looks to me like I have got quite a few of master processes that watch over one slave process. Which is good if I intended to extend the environment, but I believe most people who use this do not.

Comment: Version 5.4.20 works with 2.5GB virtual memory, slowly

Answer (score 0):

Also consider: [cloudera.com/live](http://www.cloudera.com/live) contains a full CDH 5.1 cluster + sample data, running on demand on AWS. Of course, the advantage of the VM is that you can BYOD, but if you're simply looking for a hands-on Hadoop experience, Live is a great option.